# How to show full execution query - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pg

I have some heavy queries in my server and I want to copy the full query (more than 1024 characters).

But the field from view **pg_stat_activity** dont show me more than 2014.

I saw that I can change the postgres server parameter **track_activity_query_size**, but I dont want to restart my server to apply it, and I am not sure if it works really. So, there is another table, view, function, or something I want to find it? The full execution query.

Thanks!

Comment: You can log them to the logfile: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#guc-log-statement

Comment: you can identify queries by putting `/* queryid */ select ...` in application if that is the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the views and functions that show the query string only seep a maximum of `track_activity_query_size` characters.

Unless you want to use the log file, as "a horse with no name" suggested, you'll have to restart the server.

Comment: Didint test it, but I think I will change the parameter value btw. Thanks.